# Prime factors of a separable polynomial in a non-splitting field.

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, positive-characteristic, separable-extension

Let $K$ be a field of characteristic $p$ and consider a polynomial $p(x) = x^n - a \in K[x]$, with $a \neq 0$ and $p \nmid n$. By the derivative test this is certainly separable.

Even if $p$ does not split in $K$, is it true that the prime factors of $p(x)$ in $K[x]$ (a UFD) are all distinct?

My field theory is fuzzy, but it seems that if any prime factor occurred multiple times, then in a splitting field the roots of that prime factor would all occur multiple times, violating separability. Is this valid reasoning?

Comment: Separable means no double root which means its factorization in irreducible has distinct factors. Then the main thing to know is that irreducible non-separable means $f' = 0$ so that $f= g(x^{p^m})$ with $g$ irreducible separable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $F$ be the splitting field of $p(x)$ over $K$. If $p(x)$ had repeated prime factors in $K[x]$, then $p(x)$ would have repeated roots in $F[x]$ by uniqueness of factorization. This would contradict the fact that $p(x)$ is separable as you have already shown.